# How do I only submit the highest level modal when enter is pressed?

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular module that opens a Modal A (Find Report) so the user can enter search criteria.  Modal A also has a field that opens Model B (Find Investigator) to search and find a person for Modal A.

The issue arises when I press enter with both modals open, both find functions execute.   Is there a way I can make my directive smart enough to only execute the function on Modal B in this case... whichever modal was open last? or has the highest z-index etc.

my directive

```
//Put this on a button to make it the default 
.directive('autoEnterDirective', ['$document', function($document) {
return {
  scope: {
      autoEnterDirective: "&"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var enterWatcher = function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        scope.autoEnterDirective();
        scope.$apply();
        ///console.log('ENTER')
        event.preventDefault();
        $document.unbind("keydown keypress", enterWatcher);
      }
    };
    $document.bind("keydown keypress", enterWatcher);
  }
}
}])
```

my markup for modal A (Find Report)

```
<a id="btnFind" class="button small box-shadow-inset" auto-enter-directive="findModal()" ng-click="findModal()">Find</a>
```

my markup for modal B (Find Investigator)

```
<a id="btnFind" class="button small box-shadow-inset" auto-enter-directive="findModal()" ng-click="findModal()">Find</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into one of the many issues why **modals aren't meant to be opened over other modals**...

While it may be "easiest" initially, it's not suggested or even supported (in some cases) and is hardly ever worth it as far as UX goes. It's like popup inception - there really aren't many use cases for this that make sense.

Here are a few articles worth reading:

- [Best Practices for Modals](https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-modals-overlays-dialog-windows-c00c66cddd8c)
- [Overuse of Overlays](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/overuse-of-overlays/)

Comment: basically we just showModal=false when opening the 2nd modal, then showModal=true on return.  Simple fix, thank you.